# Discord.py discord.NotFound exception

Tags: python, exception, discord, discord.py

everyone. I've been working on a few bots for my discord server and I've come across an issue in one of them which I cant seem to solve. I have a command called 'info', essentially, this command displays some information on a desired user. When I call the command `?info [user]`, it works just fine until I intentionally request the info on a user that doesn't exist to test an exception I have in place. Here'

```
@laugh.command(pass_context=True)
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if ctx.message.channel.name != "admin":
        await laugh.send_message(ctx.message.author, "Sorry, you need to be in a text channel called 'admin' for that.")
        return
    if not ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
        return
    if not user:
        user = ctx.message.author
    try:
        minfo = ("""
{0}'s ID is: {1}
{0}'s status is: {2}
{0}'s highest role is: {3}
{0} joined at: {4}""".format(user.name, user.id, user.status, user.top_role, user.joined_at))
        embed = discord.Embed(title = user.name, description = minfo, color = 0x00D2FF)
        await laugh.say(embed = embed)
    except discord.NotFound:
        await laugh.say("User not found.")
```

When I run this code and give a non-existent user as parameters, my exception doesn't work, instead, I get this output to my console:

```
Ignoring exception in command info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 367, in invoke
    yield from self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 345, in prepare
    yield from self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 304, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = yield from self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 223, in transform
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 221, in transform
    return (yield from self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument))
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 184, in do_conversion
    return instance.convert()
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 100, in convert
    raise BadArgument('Member "{}" not found'.format(self.argument))
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Member "test" not found
```

I've looked at countless examples and forums posts and the only knowledge I've gained was that the source of the error is in `async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):`, any ideas on what I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error handling for commands is a little weird.  When you specify a converter for the argument `user`, that conversion takes place outside of the body of the command coroutine.  To handle it, you must write an error handler coroutine, and associate it with the command in question.

```
@laugh.command(pass_context=True)
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if ctx.message.channel.name != "admin":
        await laugh.send_message(ctx.message.author, "Sorry, you need to be in a text channel called 'admin' for that.")
        return
    if not ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
        return
    if not user:
        user = ctx.message.author
    minfo = ("""
{0}'s ID is: {1}
{0}'s status is: {2}
{0}'s highest role is: {3}
{0} joined at: {4}""".format(user.name, user.id, user.status, user.top_role, user.joined_at))
    embed = discord.Embed(title = user.name, description = minfo, color = 0x00D2FF)
    await laugh.say(embed = embed)

@info.error
async def info_error(ctx, error): # This might need to be (error, ctx), I'm not sure
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await laugh.say('I could not find that user')
```

You can read the documentation for error handlers, and the rest of the `discord.ext.commands` module, in the [documentation for the rewrite branch.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)

If you're going to be doing a lot of work with the commands extension, it may make sense to convert your code now so that you can work with accurate documentation.