# Select Random xx answer python bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How to make python bot pick a random name. For example if I provide a list of
answers.

```
answers = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "frog", "gun"]

@bot.command()  
async def choose(k : int):
    """Chooses between multiple choices."""
    if 0 <= k <= 50:
        await bot.say("This is your random {} pick".format(k))
        embed = discord.Embed(description='\n'.join(random.choices(answers, k=k)))
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
    else:
        await bot.say("Invalid number")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482889/get-random-sample-from-list-while-maintaining-ordering-of-items?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: use random, use for loop to iterate x amount of times, inside loop print randint index of the list? something like that anyway.

Comment: As for replying in the same channel, have you looked at the basic example bot from the github repo? https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/basic_bot.py

Comment: That looks reasonable to me.  What about it isn't working?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  i updated my code it picks but only 1 answers. it needs to pick random xx amount mentioned from list. `!pick 10`  also reply should be in embed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) (not `choice`) to select `n` items with replacement, if you are on Python 3.6+

```
@bot.command()  
async def choose(k : int):
    """Chooses between multiple choices."""
    if 0 <= k <= 50:
        await bot.say("This is your random {} pick".format(k))
        embed = discord.Embed(description='\n'.join(random.choices(answers, k=k)))
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
    else:
        await bot.say("Invalid number")

@choose.error
def choose_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await bot.say("Please specify how many")
```

Comment: @Demotry See my edit.  I'd double check that `Embed` code though, I'm not in a position to run it at the moment.

Comment: You can provide a default value for `k` if you want. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: [Here's an error handler example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478189/discord-py-discord-notfound-exception/49478273#49478273).  You will want to check for `commands.MissingRequiredArgument` instead of `commands.BadArgument`

Comment: To get the name of the missing parameter, you can use the `param` attribute of the [`MissingRequiredArgument`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingRequiredArgument) object `await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "**Missing an argument:** " + error.param.name)`

Comment: Yeah.  `message.content` is `"?choose"`, so `message.content.split()` is `["?choose"]`.  There is no element at index 1.

Comment: so how to make it reply in same channel with custom message `"please mention how many"` after `?choose`

Comment: Ok got it added a custom message.

Comment: hi @patrick how to make it tag author. `await bot.say("This is your random {} pick".format(k))`  for this line. `message.author.mention`

Answer (score -1):

```
import random 

answers = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "frog", "gun"]

def pick5(listOfAnswers):
    print("This is your random 5 pick:")

    for i in range(0, 5):
        myInt = random.randint(0,len(listOfAnswers)-1)
        print(listOfAnswers[myInt])
        listOfAnswers.remove(listOfAnswers[myInt])

pick5(answers)
```

This Python function picks 5 random elements out of a given list.

It iterates 5 times and uses a randomly selected integer to pull an element from the given list, then removes it to avoid duplicates. It uses the random module to accomplish this.

I don't know about getting it to discord, but I think this is what you were looking for.